# make ConfigurationProperties optional

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration

I have spring boot application which uses application.yml for configuration.
The structure is something like:

```
...
rmq:
  host: "host"
  port: 5672
...
```

In my code I have ApplicationConfig class which looks like below:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
class ApplicationConfig {
  private RabbitConfig rabbitConfig;
}

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "rmq")
class RabbitConfig {
  @NotNull
  private String host;
  @NotNull
  private Integer port;
}
```

The problem is that section rmq is optional in my application.
And I want field rabbitConfig will init by null in case it is absent in application.yml.

But really if I drop rmq section in config file I've got an error (rmq.host is absent).
Is it possible to force springboot to init rabbitConfig with null in that case?

Comment: They aren't optional as they are marked `@NotNull` so you say they are optional, but in reality they aren't.

Comment: I mean that if rmq section is presented - host and port are mandatory. But if section rmq is absent in config that all rabbitConfig must be null in ApplicationConfig

Comment: You cannot as you marked them as required `@NotNull`... You can make it optional but it is a bit strange to make something optional that is marked required (at least in my mind).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@ConditionalOnProperty` for such cases. In your case, you should define it as:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "rmq")
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "rmq", name = "host", matchIfMissing = true)
class RabbitConfig {
  @NotNull
  private String host;
  @NotNull
  private Integer port;
}
```

Then it will load the bean only if there is `rmq.host` set, and if not, it will be set to `null`.

There is also an alternative that you always put i.e. rmq.enabled = true | false, and then `@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "rmq", name = "host", havingValue = true)`

Comment: This approach doesn't work for me with Spring Boot 2.4.x. I still get an error saying `Reason: Failed to bind properties under 'custom' to my.package.name.CustomSettings` even when adding this annotation to the `@ConfigurationProperties`-annotated class.